How to return JSON objects without explicit aliasing in postgresql
If I have two tables and I join them, can I return one of the values a JSON object, without having to specify all the fields?
For example, the following works:
SELECT u.*, 
json_build_object(
 'name', p.name, 
 'content', p."content") AS post
FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN post as p ON p.id = o."postId"

My question now is if I can use json_build_object (or something to that effect) simply by passing p.*, without having to manually specify all columns.
Does anyone know how this could work?

The docs tell all JSON functions. Hint look at to_json.

Using to_json as @AdrianKlaver comments will do exactly what you need.
SELECT u.*, to_json(p) AS post
FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN post as p ON p.id = o."postId";


Oh, that was easy! Not sure how I missed that. Thank you! :)
